# Property 'selectedOptions','selectedIndex','options' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, dropdown, typescript

I am working around with typescript in Sharepoint framework using No javascript approach. To get the dropdown text I am using the below code but it is not working:

`var dept = (<HTMLElement>document.getElementById("ddlDepartment").selectedOptions[0].text)`
**OR**

`var empDeptt = document.getElementById("ddlDepartment")["value"]`

`var selectedText = empDeptt.options[empDeptt.selectedIndex].text`

Please suggest any workaround.....

Answer (score 1):

HTMLElement does not have above properties, its child element "HTMLSelectElement" represents  HTML Element. So you can have some changes on the code:

```
var DropdownList = (document.getElementById("id")) as HTMLSelectElement;
```

This should be able to access "[selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)" properties and won't go against with TypeScript.

BR